# Retrieve current century with boost

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I am able to retrieve the current year by calling:

```
boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time().date().year();
```

But how can I extract the number of centuries from that year with a boost function?

Comment: It's simple arithmetic. I don't think such a function would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK a century is defined as 100 years in all locales.  There is, however, a question of when the century begins.   (do you count from zero or one?)  Assuming the Gregorian calendar, or a calendar that agrees with Pope Greg about when to start counting:

```
#include <iostream>

int yearToCentury(int year)
{
    return (year + 99) / 100;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << 1999 << ": " << yearToCentury(1999) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 2000 << ": " << yearToCentury(2000) << std::endl;
    std::cout << 2001 << ": " << yearToCentury(2001) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this result:

```
1999: 20
2000: 20
2001: 21
```

However, I could find no evidence of a function in the standard library or in boost to do this calculation for you.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with dividing by 100?

Comment: and adding one. (2014 / 100 + 1 = 21)

Comment: Add 99 before dividing.   2000 is in the 20th century.

Comment: This is the reason why I am asking for a boost function. Maybe there is one?

Answer (score 1):

First get the current date time with boost :

```
boost::posix_time::ptime timeLocal = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
auto century = GetCentury(timeLocal.date().year());
```

Method to get the current century :

```
/// <summary>Gets century from year.</summary>
/// <param name="year">The year.</param>
/// <returns>The century as int value.</returns>
int GetCentury(int year)
{
    if (year % 100 == 0)
        return year / 100;
    else
        return year / 100 + 1;
}
```